# Problem with handling large data using Boost iostreams

Tags: c++, boost, large-data, boost-iostreams

I need to handle large amount of data in memory (without using files/fstream) and I know that VS implementation of streambuf doesn't allow for that as it uses 32-bit counter (https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/388). I thought that maybe Boost could help me, but apparently it doesn't handle that properly as well (or maybe I'm missing something).

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>

namespace bs = boost::iostreams;

int main()
{
    uint64_t mb1 = 1024 * 1024;
    uint64_t gb1 = 1024 * mb1;
    uint64_t mbToCopy = 2048;

    std::vector<char> iBuffer(mb1);
    std::vector<char> oBuffer(4 * gb1);
    bs::stream<bs::array_sink> oStr(oBuffer.data(), oBuffer.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < mbToCopy; i++) {
        oStr.write(iBuffer.data(), iBuffer.size());
    }
    std::cout << oStr.tellp() << std::endl; // (1)
    oStr.seekp(0, std::ios_base::beg);
    std::cout << oStr.tellp() << std::endl; // (2)
}
```

This code works fine as long as **mbToCopy** is not bigger than 2048 and the output is:

> 2147483648
> 0

When I change **mbToCopy** to 2049 the output is:

> 2148532224
> 4294967296

As you can see, when I try to move back to the beginning of the stream (this is example usage, but I need to be able to reposition to any place in the stream) it places me way beyond the current size of the stream and stream becomes unreliable.
What's more, when I keep **mbToCopy** set to 2049 and reduce the size of **oBuffer** to 3GB **oStr.seekp** starts crashing.

Any idea if Boost provides other solutions that could help in my case?

Comment: `void main`? That's not legal.

Comment: @sehe My mistake - renamed function for demonstration purposes and didn't catch it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not using streams here at all. They seem to introduce unncessary overhead:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

static inline auto operator""_kb(unsigned long long v) { return v << 10ull; }
static inline auto operator""_mb(unsigned long long v) { return v << 20ull; }
static inline auto operator""_gb(unsigned long long v) { return v << 30ull; }

int main()
{
    std::vector<char> iBuffer(1_mb);
    std::vector<char> oBuffer(12_gb);

    auto pos = oBuffer.begin();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 8192; i++) {
        assert(std::next(pos, iBuffer.size()) <= oBuffer.end());
        pos = std::copy_n(iBuffer.begin(), iBuffer.size(), pos);
    }

    auto tellp = [&] { return std::distance(oBuffer.begin(), pos); };
    auto seekp = [&](size_t from_beg) { pos = std::next(oBuffer.begin(), from_beg); };

    std::cout << tellp() << std::endl; // (1)
    seekp(0);
    std::cout << tellp() << std::endl; // (2)
}
```

Which on my system prints, without a concern:

```
8589934592
0
```

Of course I introduced the `tellp()`/`seekp()` helpers only to make the code as similar as possible. You could also just write:

```
auto const beg = oBuffer.begin();
auto       pos = beg;

for (size_t i = 0; i < 8192; i++) {
    assert(std::next(pos, iBuffer.size()) <= oBuffer.end());
    pos = std::copy_n(iBuffer.begin(), iBuffer.size(), pos);
}

std::cout << (pos-beg) << std::endl; // (1)
pos = beg;
std::cout << (pos-beg) << std::endl; // (2)
```

With exactly the same output.

Comment: I know I can handle it without streams (already had alternative solution using arrays), but I was wondering if there's some easy way to fix this stream-based approach.
Other option is to subclass std:streambuf and override several functions to handle large data - not a fix, but can still be a good workaround.

Comment: Experience tells me it's not worth pouring lots of time into this unless I understand the **actual** requirements (usage context and access patterns). So, If you want to tell me more about why it needs to be streams, yet it's about huge swaths of data, yet it's not supposed to be persistent (or at least you've ruled out file streams)... I am happy to think along with you.

Comment: Using streams was a requirement. I ended up with custom streambuf and i/ostream and didn't use Boost at all.